# A memory issue with multiprocessing of Python: How to release the memory of process who ended their tasks

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

When we run the multiprocessing with several pools, how do we quit the process  after their tasks and drop the memory usage? I already include close() and join(). But I saw that the process still holds the memory after their jobs. How do we drop this memory?

#### For example, my code plays like below

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import pandas as pd    

def sub_test(aux):
    return sum(aux.A)
```

#### At the below four pools are generated and holds several copies of aux.

```
def test(aux):
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(sub_test, aux)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

#### I expect that the process release the memory after close and join, but they still holds.

```
#here is the main function
aux = pd.DataFrame()
aux['A'] = [1,1,1]

for x in range(10):
   test(aux)
```

#### Is there any commands that handle this issue?

---

Problems are solved.

pool.close() and pool.join() work properly.

Comment: How do you know the memory is not being released?

Comment: Activity monitor shows memory usage per process. Several Python processes (unexpectedly, more than 5 process) are appeared and they don't release a memory.

Comment: If you change `range(10)` to `range(100)`, does the activity monitor show the memory increasing? If so, by about what factor?

Comment: Thanks for a comment, Maybe your doubts are right. The python process may not keep increasing the memory but just using more than expected number of process. I would check it at night.

Comment: Good luck! <padding>

Comment: Having the exact same problem. The memory is not released but the processes have ended and are actually sleeping. In my case each process takes approx 60Mb which is a lot